# How can I pass heroku config vars to docker build?

Tags: docker, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to deploy my rails app to the Heroku using `heroku.yml`. This is my `yml` setup

```
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: cleardb-mysql
      as: DATABASE
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    RAILS_ENV: development
    DATABASE_URL: mysql2://abcdef:1234567@somewhere-someplace-123.cleardb.net/heroku_abcdefg123456
run:
  web: bin/rails server -p $PORT -b 0.0.0.0
```

and I'm using MySQL as a database. And here's my `Dockerfile` that the Heroku is using to build the image.

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5-alpine

ARG DATABASE_URL
ARG RAILS_ENV
# Adding the required dependencies
# Installing Required Gems
# Other Configs...
# Copying Gem Files
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
# Installing Gems
RUN bundle install --jobs=4 --retry=9
# Copying package and package.lock
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
# Installing node_modules
RUN yarn
# Copy everything to the from current dir to container_root
COPY . ./
#Compiling assets
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile # this precompilation step need DATABASE_URL
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

This is working as expected but the problem is I've to pass the database string in the `heroku.yml` file. Is there a way I can reference the config vars that are declared in the Heroku?

I tried this but it's not working as the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#setting-build-time-environment-variables) also saying that the config-vars declared in Heroku are not available at the build time.

```
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: cleardb-mysql
      as: DATABASE
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    RAILS_ENV: $RAILS_ENV
    DATABASE_URL: $DATABASE_URL
run:
  web: bin/rails server -p $PORT -b 0.0.0.0
```

What could be the possible workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without using the heroku.yml a possible solution is to include the env variable in the Dockerfile.
Example with Java code:

```
CMD java -Dserver.port=$PORT -DmongoDbUrl=$MONGODB_SRV  $JAVA_OPTS -jar /software/myjar.jar
```

You need to build the image locally, push and release it into the Heroku Registry: when it runs the Config Vars (ie MONGODB_SRV) are injected

Comment: Thank you but I want the Heroku to handle everything as soon as I push my code to the git.

Comment: I see. It looks like (according to doc) that you can config vars at provisioning time, using the setup.config section of the yml, something to try maybe

Comment: hey @Naresh any luck with this? I am struggling with the same thing here.. I need to access a config variable in my Dockerfile. Thanks

Comment: @jerry hi! have you solved this? same issue

Comment: no @AdilAkhmetov no luck with this...